# Form validation of pair of fields

Tags: forms, validation

I have a html form which contains a pair of project/hours fields(the project being a select field and hours an input field) that i need to validate in my form.There are about 5 of those pairs. I want the user to be notified of an incorrect submission when one of the following happens: there is no project select and hours filled in any pair;when a project is select but hours aren't defined for that project and vice-versa. 
How would I go about validating my fields in a pair?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a button is clicked by the user when the user thinks he is finished, you can check the selects and inputs with Jquery. If something is not ok, then tell the user and prevent the button from doing anything else.